# Illustrator Script to Select specific sublayer Text of specific Layer

Tags: illustrator-scripting

I'm a noob at scripting in Illustrator, but all of my search and trial and error didn't get me far.

I'm trying to select a specific text of a layer and change the visiblity in a Structure like this:

```
Layer1
Layer2
    Text layer to hide
    Sublayer
Layer3
```

Currently my Code looks like this:

```
var aDoc = app.activeDocument;
var layerToSelect = aDoc.layers["Layer2"].layers["Text layer to hide"];
layerToSelect.visible = false;
```

In the project the layer i'm trying to change has a special character in it ü. I don't know if that is a Problem.

Can someone help me understand what im doing wrong?

Thank you